# deriving array values from yaml file

Tags: json, xml, yaml, mule4

I have a requirement where my input XML is:

```
<Rule>
    <IdValueList>
        <RuleValue Id='Engineer' Value='Eng' />
        <RuleValue Id='Contractor' Value='IND' />
        <RuleValue Id='Doctor' Value='UK' />
        <RuleValue Id='Contractor' Value='KAR' />
    </IdValueList>
</Rule>
```

We need to validate firstly if attribute Id of element RuleValue (`RuleValue.@Id`) has value 'Contractor'. If it does not contain it then the message should not be processed further.

Next, we need to validate if the same `RuleValue` element has attribute `@Value` as either 'IND' or 'KAR'. If not, message should not be processed further.

Here is where I need help/inputs:

In a YAML file we need to store the values like `ContractDetails = [{'IN','IND'},{'KA','BNG'}]` for further processing.

If Contractor has a value of 'IND' Then it should be mapped to:

```
{
 geography : 'IN', 
 LineOfBusiness : 'IND'
} // from yaml file
```

If Contractor has a value of 'KAR' Then it should mapped to:

```
{
 geography : 'KA', 
 LineOfBusiness : 'BNG'
} // from yaml file
```

Comment: The problem that you want to resolve is not clear. Is it the validation, the transformation or both? If both, they to be two different problems, which should be in two different questions.

Comment: Can you add the text of the YAML file? And what you want with the JSON mapping that you have added in question

Answer (score 0):

If you want to transform the XML input to the sample outputs one way to do it is to filter to leave only the element with the Id attribute equal to "Contractor", then transform it using the Value attribute as the key.

The ContractDetails provided is not valid YAML so I represented it as a valid YAML object, where the keys are the expected Value attributes, and the values are what we need to add to the output dynamically.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var ContractDetails = read(
"ContractDetails:
    IND: 
        geography: IN
        LineOfBusiness: IND
    KAR:
        geography: KA
        LineOfBusiness: BNG"
    ,"application/yaml").ContractDetails
---
payload.Rule.IdValueList 
    filterObject ((value, key, index) -> key.@Id as String == "Contractor") 
    mapObject ((value, key, index) -> {
        geography: ContractDetails[key.@Value].geography,
        LineOfBusiness: ContractDetails[key.@Value].LineOfBusiness}
    )
```

Output:

```json
{
  "geography": "IN",
  "LineOfBusiness": "IND"
}
```

If you read the YAML from a file you can use the p() operator to read the property instead of defining it inline (example `var ContractDetails = p("ContractDetails")`).